# My media queries aren´t working well

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to use these six media queries in my project:

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) {} //for small mobiles and large mobile in portrait
@media screen and (min-width:480px) {} //larg mobiles and mobiles in landscape
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {} //for small tablets
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {} //for normal tablets
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {} //for normal tablets, laptop, desktop
@media screen and (min-width:1281px) {} //large laptop, desktop
```

But something strange happens, only my first media query is working fine; the others don't work, and the others work combined. For example, in my  `@media screen and (min-width:1281px)` media query, the result I have is the header and footer of this media query and the body of my media query (min-width:480px).

Does somebody out there know why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the queries themselves http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/RyL5E/embedded/result/ check the fiddle and resize the window.

Comment: Would it be possible to see an example of this occurring? Otherwise, it's a bit trickier to troubleshoot. As a general reminder, remember that if you have no overriding CSS styles for your body after the 480px media query, then you will see those styles continue when your viewport width is 1281px.

Comment: Wow.. I really dont understand!! I have all media queries in the same CSS file,because I saw many examples doing like this, but, do you think that this can be the problem?

Comment: Im using viewport:  <meta name="viewport" content="device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">. I will see if I can post in jsfiddle my code!

Comment: Does changing all of the `min-width`s to `max-width` help any? Or perhaps also adding a `max-width` to each (like `(min-width: 320px and max-width: 479px)`? Most likely some styles are not being overwritten each time so they cascade to the next media query